# Postgres Issue Isolation level

Tags: java, postgresql

Lot of SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL appears in process list in Postgres 9.0 .

What are reasons for this and when it appears ?. All are in idle state.
How to disable this ?

Comment: Do you have an application running against this database that is using connection pooling?   Connection pools often do this sort of thing to ensure the connection is alive.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that with *process list* you mean the system view `pg_stat_activity` (accessible in pgAdmin III in the "statistics" tab or with "Tools/Server Status").

Since you say that the connections are idle, the `query` column does not show an active query, it shows the last query that has been issued in this database connection. I don't know which ORM or connection pooler you are using, but some software in your stack must insert these statements routinely at the end of a database action.

I wouldn't worry about them, this statements are not resource intensive and probably won't cause you any trouble.

If you really need to get rid of them, figure out which software in your stack causes them and investigate there.